# how to prevent specific word to search result laravel

Tags: php, regex, laravel, eloquent

I need to prevent some specific searches like a username.

the scenario is when I search auth username I get all friends but if I search auth username I don't want to search result,

here's my query

```
$searchVal = $request->input('search');
```

```
$friend_data = Friend::with('getAccept', 'getRequest')->where('status', '1')->where(static function ($q) use ($user) {
            $q->where('user_id', $user->id)->orWhere('ref_id', $user->id);
        })->where(function ($q1) use ($searchVal) {
            if($searchVal) {
                $q1->whereHas('getRequest', function ($q) use ($searchVal) {
                    $q->where('username', 'LIKE', '%' . $searchVal . '%');                
                });
                $q1->orWhereHas('getAccept', function ($q) use ($searchVal) {
                    $q->where('username', 'LIKE', '%' . $searchVal . '%');                    
                });
            }
        })->get();
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: what are the words you want to prevent from searching?

Comment: @Makdous I  want to prevent the auth username.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace `if($searchVal)` in your `where` function with `if($searchVal !== Auth::user()->username)` and that should exclude the *auth username* results.